# MySQL on Ubuntu Case Sensitivity Issues

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

1. DB was designed for SQL Server initially.  Back then all table names were mixed case. For example, `UserTasks`.
2. Hundreds of stored procedures were written on these tables and those stored procedures use mixed case table names.
3. DB was migrated to MySQL (on Windows) and during that process table names were automatically converted to all lower case but code inside stored procedures was converted to MySQL format without changing the table name cases.
4. We just migrated to Ubuntu and everything stopped working because MySQL can no longer find those tables used in SQL statements in stored procedures.

Is there a easy way around this?  I know the hard way. Open each one of those 550 stored procedures and change table names to lower case one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Case sensitivity of table names is a complex story on MySQL, because it works on all types of environments: Windows, which is case-insensitive, Unix and Linux, which is case-sensitive, and also MacOS which is sort of a hybrid.

You might be able to use the `lower_case_table_names` option. I can't be sure, because I don't use that option myself, I don't use Windows, and I seldom use MySQL stored procedures, so I'm not sure how this will interact with the procedure code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to work.  I hope there are no case sensitivity issues with table column names because in stored procedures even they are sometimes right case and sometimes all lower case that do not match with real table column name cases.